# Deleting items from AutoPopulatingList

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've implemented successfully an AutoPopulatingList. I've a javascript incrementing the id and on the background Spring is creating my beautiful list.

I've encountered some problems on the deletion of the items btw. I'm using a Wizard Controller and I've tried to "go back" and delete a couple of items. Then, going forward... surprise! The items are still there!

So, how can I force Spring to create a new AutoPopulatingList everytime? Or what I'm missing?

This is my list with the factory:

```
private AutoPopulatingList<Event> events = new AutoPopulatingList<Event>(new EventElementFactory());

public class EventElementFactory implements ElementFactory { 
    @Override
    public Event createElement(int index) throws ElementInstantiationException {            
        Event e = new Event(); 
        e.setModContr(""); 
        e.setDesc("");          
        return e; 
    } 
}
```

and I've this initBinder in the controller (don't know why but it's not working without):

```
binder.setAutoGrowNestedPaths(false);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the end I've resolved this way:

In my jsp I've added an hidden field

```
<input name="_clearEventList" type="hidden" value="true" />
```

and in my Controller

```
protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) throws Exception {
    if(Boolean.valueOf(request.getParameter("_clearEventList"))) {
        ((MyForm)binder.getTarget()).getEvents().clear();
    }
    binder.setAutoGrowNestedPaths(false);
}
```

so this will clear my list just on the going forward (or backward) from that page, and force Spring to repopulate it. :)